# Разделение и увеличение выбранной области в фотографии

Tags: java, изображения

Каким образом можно реализовать разделение выбранной области в фотографии на, к примеру, 4 плитки? В дальнейшем эти плитки будут выглядеть как матрица для последующего *zoom*'а.

Пример. Есть фотография:

```
X0,0 X0,1
Y1,0 Y1,1
```

где `Х`,`У` - плитки.

Выбираю область `X0,0 Y1,1` и разделяю её на 4 части. Надо увеличить эту область.

Что-то подобное нашел на [этом YouTube-канале](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeLQaOBMuWk), но там только обрезание выбранной области и нет плиток, которые нужны мне.

[image: Схема]

Разбил изображение на плитки:

[image: плитки]

Почему-то в `Panel` не рисуется картинка. Сделал это так:

```
public class TileList extends JPanel 
{
    private static final int width = 64; //width of a tile
    private static final int height = width;
    private int col = 1;
    private int row = 1;
    private BufferedImage image;
    File tilesetImage = new File("путь");
    BufferedImage tileset[];

    public void loadAndSplitImage (File loadImage) 
    {
        try
        {
            image = ImageIO.read(loadImage);
        }
        catch (Exception error) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: cannot read tileset image.");
        } //end try/catch
        col = image.getWidth() / width;
        row = image.getHeight() / height;
        tileset = new BufferedImage[col * row];
    } //end loadAndSplitImage

    public TileList() {
        loadAndSplitImage(tilesetImage);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col, 1, 1));
        setBackground(Color.black);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int q = 0; //keeps track of tile #
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {    
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                tileset[q] = new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType());
                tileset[q] = image.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
                panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(tileset[q])));
                add(panel);
                panel.setVisible(true);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(tileset[q])));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                x += width;
                q++;
            } //end for loop
            y += height;
            x = 0;
        } //end for loop
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "InfoBox: ");
    } //end constructor
} //end
```

Осталось только увеличить выбранную область. Как это сделать? К примеру, область

```
0,1 0,2 
1,1 1,2
```

[image: пример области]

Comment: @Regent сейчас я прикреплю фотографию, и сразу все станет ясно )

Comment: @Regent добавил код и фото )

Comment: Теперь остаётся надеяться, что кто-нибудь разберётся в вопросе и найдёт решение.

Comment: если есть доступ по индексу к tileset и там лежит BufferedImage, может проще использовать Scalr из imgscalr-lib, куда передать BI и размер?